# :mksession session file includes nonprintable characters

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, sessions

I have been having some problems using UltiSnips with vim. It seems that `:mksession` is adding a bunch of nonprintable characters to my session file(s). When this is sourced to restore my session, [UltiSnips has a problem dealing with these nonprintable characters](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/627). Does anyone know why vim might be adding these nonprintable characters to my session file?

The following are the two vim commands that I'm using to save a session and source a session.

`nmap <F2> :wa<CR>:mksession! $HOME/vim_session<CR> " Write session to file`

`nmap <F3> :wa<CR>:source $HOME/vim_session<CR> " Load session from file`

[image: Screenshot of gVim session file with many nonprintable characters]

Comment: Are you by any chance "lazy"-loading the UltiSnips plugin? Perhaps the cause is *not* related to unprintable characters, but with plugin loading "moment".

Comment: Yeah, the developer of UltiSnips thinks it's not a problem with unprintable characters, either. However, it's weird that those characters are being inserted. Any idea why that would be? I'm using Vundle to manage my plugins. It does not allow me to load UltiSnips lazily like NeoBundle does. So, no, I'm not lazily loading them. They are being loaded as soon as a session is restored.

Comment: Why do you think it's weird? This is the default behavior.

Comment: Really? Why are there `device control 2` characters, above, and `end of medium` characters? See [this table](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm) if you're not familiar with control-key sequences (I'm not familiar).

Comment: In Vim, you can literally type `Ctrl-V` `Enter` to get something equivalent to what you would otherwise type as "\r", "\n", "\<CR>" etc. (depending on context). Vim would then show this as "^V^M", which actually means "literally a carriage return". What I see in your screenshot *is* what UltiSnips author told you - Vim representation of raw characters, replacing (but equivalent) to the ones you specified in your maps.

Comment: Right, I totally understand that much. What I don't understand is why those raw characters would be in my session file. Newlines, carriage returns, line feeds, those are understandable. `bel`, `device control 2`, `end of medium` characters don't belong in a session file as far as I can determine. That's what this question is asking: Why are weird (i.e. not formatting/newline characters, but other strange raw characters) showing up in my session file?